# for loop with ArrayList in java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

i got a Productclass stored in ArrayList myValues.
I want to go trough each xth ( for example each 3th) element and have the user
add some Integer values to that class.

In my for(...) he tells me: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable. I wonder if i messed up some of the .get(j) or if i have to synchronize my methods so that the size wont change ( there is no multi-threading but maybe thats why i get an error?
) or the solution is more simple.

Thx

```
public void prioPerProduct (){

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Please enter storing and upgrading cost:");

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    int storingCost = 0;
    int ruestCost = 0;
    int countRes = countRessources;
    int sizemyValues = myValues.size();
    for(int j = 0; j < sizemyValues; j = j+countRes){

        System.out.println("Please enter storingcost " + myValues.get(j).getProduct() +":" );
        try {
            storingCost = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("No number entered");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No number entered");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter upgradingcost " + myValues.get(j).getProduct() +":" );
        try {
            ruestCost = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("No number entered");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No number entered");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myValues.get(j).setstoringCost(storingCost);
        myValues.get(j).setupgradingCost(ruestCost);


    }


}
```

Comment: Could you provide the complete stacktrace of the error ?

Comment: nvm, it works now, didnt change anything but suddenly it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable** is generally caused by something like this:

**methodCall() = somvalue...**

The left hand side must be a variable rather than a method call. Your code looks fine in this regard.
The code where you declare your model class and a full stack trace are more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the set method to change the value of an object inside of an ArrayList.

```
myValues.set(j,myValues.get().setstoringCost(storingCost));
myValues.set(j,myValues.get().setupgradingCost(ruestCost));
```